# jQuery validation consolidate errors

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Currently using [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), is it possible to consolidate all the errors into just 1 msg?

I want to be able to show a modal box if any of the required fields isn't fulfilled.
Simply saying 'Please complete all required fields'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "invalidHandler" option callback, see example in docs  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions